# Google Geocoding Inaccuracy (UK)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have been working recently with the geocoding API and had a few questions regarding the accuracy of geocoding requests. If I geocode an address using the API and then reverse geocode the coordinates generated from the initial result the two street addresses usually do not match (usually by two houses or so).

Is this an issue with geocoding accuracy or reverse? Is there anything I can do to combat this or is this merely inherent within the API. If so is there any way that I can provide a margin of error when performing these actions, i.e is this inaccuracy documented anywhere?

Obviously it is to be expected that the geocoding API cannot be completely accurate 100% of the time, but I would like to able to see some numbers or documentation on the subject is anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Best,

Chris.

*Edit* I realise this is an old question but it was never answered and if recently come across the issue again, and have been questioned on this by clients paying for business licences before.

Comment: Some code examples of the conversions you are performing would be helpful.

Comment: Do you any example addresses that exhibit the problem?

Comment: I'll have a look into posting a fiddle later on, as I said the issues arose a while ago and are merely resurfacing, also a re-write will be required to move the geocodibg out of the back end.

Comment: perhaps you should try this on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The level of detail in the data that Google has/provides varies from location to location.

The [`GeocoderLocationType`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderLocationType) in the [`GeocoderGeometry`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry) you receive indicate how precise the geocoding is:

APPROXIMATE

The returned result is approximate.

GEOMETRIC_CENTER

The returned result is the geometric center of a result such a line (e.g. street) or polygon (region).

RANGE_INTERPOLATED

The returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections). Interpolated results are generally returned when rooftop geocodes are unavailable for a street address.

ROOFTOP

The returned result reflects a precise geocode.

Comment: This seems reasonable thinking about it. Geocoding say 24 whatever street would give me a set of long/lats, and then reverse geocoding it would give me 22 whatever street. This is probably due to the street counting as a Geometric center result and these being the coordinates provided from the original geocode.